# Can I use return to return to the start of an if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, return

I'm currently programming some homework, and we have to make a program that turns a hindu-arabic numeral into a roman numeral. I've already made the first part, where my teacher said we had to make sure the number is in between 1 and 3999. My algorithm so far is like this:

```
if (num-1000) > 0 {
    add M to output
    num -= 1000
    return if
}
else {
    (repeat for other digits, aka 500, 100, 50, and so on)
}
```

The problem is, I don't know if it's even possible. All the Stack Overflow pages I've seen say that I should use while statements for this, but since we haven't tackled while statements yet (even though I've self-learned it) we can't use while loops. So, can I use return to return to the start of an if statement?

Comment: No.  You're inventing language syntax.

Comment: Nothing about the task of converting arabic numeral into roman numerals requires any kind of looping.

Comment: Yes, that's while. Your task cannot be accomplished without a loop, i.e. `while` ` do while` or `for`. Well there's the option of `go to` but using that at this stage of learning would inspire some very very bad habits so I wholeheartedly discourage it.

Comment: `num / 1000` will tell you how many 1000s there are.  `num % 1000` will give you what remains.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik am I missing something? How can you convert an arbitrarily large Arabic number into Roman numerals without a loop or a recursion?

Comment: @TheMattrix "*we haven't tackled while statements yet*" -  then what HAVE you tackled so far? Chances are, you are expected to use only what you have been taught up to this point.

Comment: On second thought I think you are supposed to use a bunch of ifs since you have an upper bound

Comment: No.  To get an effect like you describe, place the code (`if` statement, its block, etc) into a loop.     You may need to introduce other book-keeping (variables tracking state, etc) to ensure control returns to the start of the loop when appropriate.

Comment: Anything fundamentally computable can be coded in C++.   But you need to stick with the rules of the language - and, if some concept is not described in a way that can be readily translated into code,  change the description as often as needed.   It is easier to change a functional description of a small series of calculations than it is to change C++ so any description you offer can be mapped directly into C++.

Comment: A loop can be used [if you make the conversion table driven](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a051cc197a751737).

Comment: Arabic to Roman is not as easy as the other way round. E.g. 98 is XCVIII. 1997 is MCMXCVII. Suggest you work the other way round solution first.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a `while`. You can also achieve that with a `go to`  but using that at this stage of learning would inspire some very very bad habits so I wholeheartedly discourage it. Another way you could do this is with recursion but that is an even more advance topic.

Given your restrictions (no loops, a number between 1 and 3999) I think you are supposed to use a bunch of ifs. Something like this pseudocode:

```
if (n >= 3000)
   add 'M'
else if (n >= 2000)
   add 'MM'
else if (n >= 1000)
   add 'MMM'

n = n % 1000;

if (n >= 900)
   add 'CM'

// and so on
```